# Package is not in Podfile but is still working – how?

Tags: podfile, intercom

I am switching from [tinycreative/react-native-intercom](https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom) to [intercom/intercom-react-native](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-react-native). In the former's docs, it says to add Intercom to my Podfile like this:

[image: screenshot of Intercom docs]

So, since I am uninstalling it I want to remove it. However, when I search for it, it's not there. Here is the Podfile in question:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '7.0.0'
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'ProjectName' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )
  
  target 'ProjectNameTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Uncomment this line if you want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  # Pods for Everybody
  # pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.14.0'
  # pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.14.0'
  # pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.13.0'
  pod 'appcenter-core', path: '../node_modules/appcenter/ios'
  pod 'appcenter-analytics', path: '../node_modules/appcenter-analytics/ios'
  pod 'appcenter-crashes', path: '../node_modules/appcenter-crashes/ios'
  # CodePush plugin dependency
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
  # geolocation
  pod 'react-native-geolocation', path: '../node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation'
  pod 'RNStoreReview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-store-review/ios'
  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'
  pod 'react-native-cookies', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-cookies/cookies'
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    end
  end
```

What's going on here? How is it still working if it's not being imported? Appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, I think the answer turned out to be that some dependencies are not explicitly imported, but implicitly, and this ended up being one of them. Not quite sure how, maybe something to do with the required node_modules at the top, but that's my best guess.